# What is the preferred way of testing separate components connected by Redux using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, react-testing-library

- I am aware of Redux documentation at https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests. My setup function wraps each rendered component with `<Provider>`, thus it has access to the store.
- I am aware of React Testing Library philosophy of testing integrated
  behavior rather than implementation.

I have an App where 2 different, deeply nested components interact with each other by Redux.
`Component A` has a set of buttons and `Component B` changes its view when button is pressed.

[image: App sample schema]

I have 2 approaches to test that.

**Isolated**

1. Render Component A
2. Test that it dispatches actions correctly.
3. Render Component B
4. Dispatch same actions inside of the test
5. Check that component reacts to dispatches correctly.

**Integrated**

1. Render the whole app
2. Simulate clicks on Component A
3. Check that Component B reacts correctly, without manually calling any Redux functions.

I feel that Integrated approach matches the RTL philosophy. But I can not accept the fact that I need to render the whole app to test functionality related to exact component. I don't even know where to put such a test.

Should it be `ComponentB.test.tsx`? Or `App.test.tsx` since I am rendering the whole app?

If I have a lot of such tests, `App.test.tsx` will be cluttered.
Or should I put it inside `ComponentB.test.tsx`, but render the `App` component inside the test?

Or should I accept the fact that I am testing implementation when tests are related to Redux?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Came across this exact use case too and interested in how you solved it in the end?

Answer (score -1):

React testing library is good for unit and integration tests. In your case you should write 2 tests in:

- ComponentA.test.tsx
- ComponentB.test.tsx

utils/renderWithProvider.ts

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PreloadedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { setupStore, AppStore, RootState } from 'store';

interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'> {
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>;
  store?: AppStore;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const renderWithProviders = (
  component: ReactElement,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState)
  }: // ...renderOptions
  ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
) => render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>);
```

ComponentA.test.tsx

```
import { cleanup, screen, RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { renderWithProviders } from 'utils/renderWithProviders';
import ComponentA from '..';

const dispatchMock = jest
  .spyOn(store, 'dispatch')
  .mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
jest.mock('store/yourData/yourDataSlice', () => ({
  setYourData: (data) => dispatchMock(data)
}));

describe('<ComponentA />', () => {
  let view: RenderResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    view = renderWithProviders(<ComponentA />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should render', () => {
    expect(view.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('click on button', async () => {
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    await userEvent.click(button);

    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some data');
  });
});
```

...
Testing of whole application is a task of e2e-testing.